# phone gap in blackberry

Tags: javascript, blackberry, cordova

I am using the phonegap in my blackberry application.I need to get the button clicked and go to the next form.please tell me for that i need to use the phone.js or to create my own javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a javascript framework to make your life easy :)

Try http://jquerymobile.com/ that works very good in BB OS v5+, Android, Iphone and so on.

Good Luck!